# How to publish Environment Dashboard on Jenkins to Users

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dashboard

I am using a pluing on Jenkins called Environment Dashboard Plugin,

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Environment+dashboard+plugin

I would like to publish this dashboard to users with no access to Jenkins.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, have created a project and global role for anonymous user using Role Based matrix.